# UIButton addTarget:action:event: doesn't call selector on other class

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, target

**EDIT:**
In my ViewController i am adding multiple buttons to its view.

**ViewController1.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController

-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController1.m**

```
#import "MyViewCreatorClass.h"

@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.view addSubView:[MyViewCreatorClass createButtonWithParentView:self]];
}

-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"tapped");
}
```

The implementation for creating the button is inside the class 'MyViewCreatorClass'

**MyViewCreatorClass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MyViewCreatorClass : NSObject

+ (UIButton*)createButtonWithParentView:(ViewController1*)parentView;

@end
```

**MyViewCreatorClass.m**

```
#import "MyViewCreatorClass.h"

@implementation MyViewCreatorClass
+ (UIButton*)createButtonWithParentView:(ViewController1*)parentView {

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:....];
//some other implementation (title, color etc.)

[button addTarget:parentView action:(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return button;
}

@end
```

At first i had this implementation inside `ViewController1` and it worked fine, but now
<s>the warning "undeclared selector 'buttonTapped:'" shows up</s> (this was solved by declaring the method buttonTapped: in ViewController1.h)
the method won't get called as i moved this method into `MyViewCreatorClass`.

I know that `parentView` needs to be an instantiated object, and it is. In another method of `MyViewCreatorClass` i'm also setting some views delegate to `parentView` and it works.
I even tried to use this method as an instance method not a class method but it did not work either. 
What could it be that prevents the method from being called?
**Additional question:**
One could also use protocols to achieve this (comments). I know how to use protocols, but sadly i don't know how to implement this so a button calls a method on touchUpInside.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to show more code.  Does `MyViewCreatorClass` even know what `ViewController1` is (i.e. it's seen its declaration)?  For stuff like this you are better off using protocols rather than concrete classes as that makes it's more reusable across different view controllers.

Comment: did you created a method for button tapped?

Comment: Yes, 'MyViewCreatorClass' knows what 'ViewController1' is. I imported it in the .h file. As i said, setting a delegate works. And yes, i declared the 'buttonTapped' method (as is said, it worked when the code was inside 'ViewController1') : '-(void)tappedHeaderButton:(UIButton*)sender{}'. And if i were to use protocols, how would i implement such a protocol to let the button call a method in my ViewController1 instance

Comment: Have you declared the method for `buttonTapped:` inside the *header* for ViewController1?

Comment: Thanks, forgot that... Warning is gone but method doesn't get called ?